# Passing partial REST responses as they are received

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, restsharp

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses RestSharp to connect to a 3rd party in order to receive a list of domain names and then more details about each domain later in the result.

I believe the response is coming in partial packets and RestSharp is waiting until all packets have been received before outputting the data in a deserialized format.

The payload in question looks like the following. "header" gets populated first and is the response I want to return to the view immediately. The rest of the data is less time sensitive:

```
[
{"header":{"names":["test.1","test.2","test.3","test.4","test.5","test.6"]}}
,
{"name":"test.1","can":"transfer?"}
,
{"name":"test.2","can":"transfer?"}
,
{"name":"test.3","can":"transfer?"}
,
{"name":"test.4","can":"transfer?"}
,
{"name":"test.5","can":"transfer?"}
,
{"name":"test.6","can":"register"}
]
```

There are currently two implementations for the execution, one synchronous and one async:

```
public T ExecuteGetRequest<T>(RestRequest request) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        IRestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);

        if (response.ErrorException == null)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public Task<T> ExecuteGetRequestAsync<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        _client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) => { source.SetResult(response.Data); });
        return source.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is a local API call for the application to implement the search using async that looks like this:

```
public async Task<DomainSearchResults> DomainSearchAsync(string domain)
{
    var request = _client.CreateRequest("domain-search/{domain}", Method.GET);
    request.AddUrlSegment("domain", domain);
    var response = await _client.ExecuteGetRequestAsync<List<DomainSearch>>(request);
    return new DomainSearchResults(response);
}
```

Which then inpterprets the response and gives the client the relevant search results.

This works fine in the sense that when all the data has been sent by the 3rd party, the object is returned to the view and populated accordingly. However, the full completion of the request can take up to 20 seconds, which is not particularly helpful to the user.

Is there a way I can adapt the ExecuteGetRequestAsync to start sending incomplete responses back to the calling view before the full response has been received?

My initial attempt looks a lot like this:

```
public Task<T> ExecuteGetRequestAsyncIncomplete<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        _client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) =>
        {
            source.SetResult(response.Data);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent)
            {
                // Somehow return part of this response
            }

        });
        return source.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Working on from @Evk 's answer, here's what the new call to return a partial result looks like, specifically for this scenario:

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteGetRequestPartial<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{

    try
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        request.ResponseWriter = (st) => {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(st))
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                // read response 100 chars at a time
                char[] buffer = new char[1];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(buffer, 0, read);
                    // now here you have your partial response
                    // you need to somehow parse it and feed to your view
                    // note that you should wait until you get some meaningful part, like first "header" element
                    // for example at some point there might be ["header":{"names":["te < partial response
                    if (sb.ToString().Contains("header") && sb.ToString().EndsWith("}"))
                    {
                        sb.Append("}]");
                        source.SetResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sb.ToString()));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // at this point you have full response in sb
            }
        };
        await _client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<T>(request);
        return await source.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

In short, the buffer has been reduced to 1 char so that we know where we are in the string. Then to turn the partial result into valid JSON, we check for the end of the object and then close it by manually adding the extra "}]" to the result and returning that.

Nice one Evk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, http status "Partial Content" has nothing to do with your case. It's for responses to requests with Range header.

What you need instead is read response stream as it comes, not waiting for full response to be delivered and deserialized. It's easier to do that with regular HttpWebRequest, but if you want to use RestSharp, it's also possible. Note that you will have to manually deserialize **partial** (so, invalid) json. Here is a sketch:

```
    public static Task<T> ExecuteGetRequestAsync<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new() {
        var client = new RestClient("http://google.com");
        try {
            var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
            request.ResponseWriter = (st) => {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(st)) {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    // read response 100 chars at a time
                    char[] buffer = new char[100];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                        sb.Append(buffer, 0, read);
                        // now here you have your partial response
                        // you need to somehow parse it and feed to your view
                        // note that you should wait until you get some meaningful part, like first "header" element
                        // for example at some point there might be ["header":{"names":["te < partial response
                    }
                    // at this point you have full response in sb
                }
            };
            client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, null);
            return source.Task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```